# bash: kivy: command not found

Tags: bash, macos, kivy

I followed the instructions in [this link about Kivy installation "Using Homebrew with pip"](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-osx.html).

However, when I tried to run the code given below:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Hello World')

TestApp().run()
```

It gave me an error:

```
bash: kivy: command not found
```

Answer (score 3):

if you installed kivy with pip, you don't need a kivy command, you can use python directly.

```
python main.py
```

Answer (score 2):

Because I created a virtual environment to isolate all the things that needs to be installed like kivy, and I installed cython and kivy first before the homebrew, it caused the problem. Even if I use:

```
python main.py
```

instead of

```
kivy main.py
```

What I did to solve it are the following:
1. Created a new virtual environment
2. Followed the instruction in kivy in right order: (1) homebrew, (2) Cython, then (3) Kivy.
3. Used "python" command instead of "kivy" command because I installed it using pip (refer to the commenr above). For example:

```
python name_of_your_file.py
```

Kivy documentation must be confusing that's why.